# github action Error: Input required and not supplied: token

Tags: github, yaml, action

I just learned github action and YAML, and i used a yaml file example.The content is following

```
name: CI
​
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
  push:
    branches:
      - main
​
jobs:
  CI:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
​
    concurrency:
      group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.head_ref }}
      cancel-in-progress: true
​
    steps:
      - name: "Checkout"
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: recursive
          token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
​
      - name: "Add NPM secrets"
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.DEPLOY_TOKEN  }}" >> ${{ github.workspace }}/.npmrc
          cat .npmrc
​
      - name: "Install dependencies"
        run: yarn --frozen-lockfile
​
      - name: Build
        run: yarn workspace @mv-community/solidity dist
​
      - name: Type check
        run: yarn type:check
​
      - name: Lint check
        run: yarn lint
​
      - name: Solhint check
        run: yarn workspace @mv-community/solidity solhint:check
​
      - name: Test
        run: yarn workspace @mv-community/solidity test
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03IUV.png)

I push this to my github repository, it occurred as above.I searched for solution, but failed. Anyone can help me?

Comment: It looks like the `ACCESS_TOKEN` secret isn't set properly. To check out the repository that hosts the workflow, you don't have to provide a token to `actions/checkout`.

Comment: You can probably just remove the `token:` line.

Comment: as for the other comments, as much as that makes it work, it doesn't explain why this isn't working.  Because to me, this is a "doesn't work as advertised" problem.